# SSH freezes after entering password, Fedora

Tags: ssh, fedora, ssh-agent

I recently installed Fedora 30 on my new laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad E495).

My problem is: when I try to connect to my server through SSH, is asking me the password. I enter the password and after this `ssh` screen freezes, no bash, nothing; after 20 minutes, when I receive a logout message.

This only happens on Fedora. I installed Ubuntu 19.04 and works perfectly, I try on a different network as well (another different public IP) and works, from my network or from another distro or computer works with out problem.

edit:
adding ssh debug

```
ssh -p 2022 user@mydomain.domain
```

```
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1c FIPS  28 May 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host apperturedev.es originally apperturedev.es
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'
debug2: match not found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-,gss-group1-sha1-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host apperturedev.es originally apperturedev.es
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'
debug2: match found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-,gss-group1-sha1-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
debug2: resolving "apperturedev.es" port 2022
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to apperturedev.es [92.57.33.203] port 2022.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/adrian/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/adrian/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/adrian/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/adrian/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/adrian/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/adrian/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/adrian/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/adrian/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/adrian/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/adrian/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to apperturedev.es:2022 as 'adrian'
debug3: put_host_port: [apperturedev.es]:2022
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/adrian/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/adrian/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [apperturedev.es]:2022
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:bBHAEJPIGanPT6L38EoNliL7/TGrhNEKd9yRQf4fH94
debug3: put_host_port: [92.57.33.203]:2022
debug3: put_host_port: [apperturedev.es]:2022
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/adrian/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/adrian/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [apperturedev.es]:2022
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/adrian/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/adrian/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [92.57.33.203]:2022
debug1: Host '[apperturedev.es]:2022' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/adrian/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/adrian/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/adrian/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/adrian/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/adrian/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/adrian/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/adrian/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/adrian/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/adrian/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/adrian/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/adrian/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/adrian/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/adrian/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/adrian/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/adrian/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/adrian/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
adrian@apperturedev.es's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to apperturedev.es ([92.57.33.203]:2022).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 5 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x48
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_PATH
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
debug1: Sending env LANGUAGE = 
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env SHELL_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env GDK_CORE_DEVICE_EVENTS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env GTK2_RC_FILES
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env SSH_ASKPASS
debug1: Sending env LANG = es_ES.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE
debug3: Ignored env KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env PROFILEHOME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT_PATH
debug3: Ignored env KONSOLE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env KDE_SESSION_UID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_CLASS
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env COLORFGBG
debug3: Ignored env KDE_SESSION_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env PAM_KWALLET5_LOGIN
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env GS_LIB
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env KDEDIRS
debug3: Ignored env QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR
debug3: Ignored env XCURSOR_THEME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env KDE_FULL_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env KONSOLE_PROFILE_NAME
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env KONSOLE_DBUS_WINDOW
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: send packet: type 1
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

config from etc, not ssh config on my home

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

# Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
#
# To modify the system-wide ssh configuration, create a  *.conf  file under
#  /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/  which will be automatically included below
Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf
```

include file ssh_config

```
# The options here are in the "Match final block" to be applied as the last
# options and could be potentially overwritten by the user configuration
Match final all
        # Follow system-wide Crypto Policy, if defined:
        Include /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config

        GSSAPIAuthentication yes

# If this option is set to yes then remote X11 clients will have full access
# to the original X11 display. As virtually no X11 client supports the untrusted
# mode correctly we set this to yes.
        ForwardX11Trusted yes

# Send locale-related environment variables
        SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
        SendEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
        SendEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
        SendEnv XMODIFIERS

# Uncomment this if you want to use .local domain
# Host *.local
```

Comment: Please run ssh with the `-vvv` option to make it print debugging information, then [edit] your question to include the debugging output. Include the actual `ssh` command that you are running, along with any relevant lines from your `.ssh/config` file.

Comment: Ok, I added to my question debug and config file of ssh and the command I'm executing

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?